# Function for converting 10 min and 30 min NETCDF time series to hourly + remove NaNs in Python?

Tags: python, netcdf

I am trying to parse through NOAA buoy NetCDF files and depending on when they were launched, the data is recorded every 10 min, 30 min, or hourly. I need all of them to be consistently hourly in Python. So, anything less than an hour needs to be averaged. I've seen methods using `cdo` and `resample` but I can't seem to get much to work.

Sample 10 min nc file I'm working with: https://dods.ndbc.noaa.gov/thredds/fileServer/data/stdmet/41053/41053h9999.nc

The three variables I care about are wave_height, average_wpd, and mean_wave_dir. I'm fine if I can replace NaNs with a number like 9999. I need a function that can convert and average any time series into hourly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try using xarray:

```
import xarray as xr

ds = xr.open_dataset("./41053h9999.nc")

ds_resampled = ds.resample(time='1H').mean() # or use other methods if you like see: http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.resample.html

# remove nans:
ds_resampled = ds_resampled.dropna('time')
```

Comment: I JUST figured this out before I saw you had it here 15 minutes ago. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work fine in CDO as follows:

```
cdo hourmean 41053h9999.nc outfile.nc
```

Output looks good when I check:

```
cdo showtime outfile.nc
```

You say, you have tried cdo, but it didn't work. If you tried the above, you may need to check your CDO version.

If you want to do this in python, you could use nctoolkit, which has a method for calling CDO:

```
import nctoolkit as nc
ds = nc.open_data("infile.nc")
ds.cdo_command("hourmean") 
ds.to_nc("outfile.nc")
```

Comment: This is my first time using CDO but I'm pretty sure I have the right version, will double check it's loaded properly in a min. Scratch that, I don't think I have it loaded in my environment although I did not get an error importing it into jupyter. Let me load it and try again.

Comment: So I have in installed and activated but am still getting the same error, it looks like it doesn't recognize `hourmean` in the command:                          **File "<ipython-input-5-d9fde347dc09>", line 1
    cdo hourmean 41053h9999.nc outfile.nc
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax**

Comment: You seem to be using CDO in python. It should be used on the terminal or by adding "!" in a jupyter notebokk

Comment: Ok, yes, thank you, it looks like it works in the terminal but I really need this to work in Python. Do you know a workaround to get it to work in python through jupyter notebook? I have a script that needs to iterate over 1,000+ files and I need it all done in python. Searching online it looks like I might need `python-cdo` but the info out there is sparse.

Comment: Is there an alternative to using cdo? I don't think I'm going to get that to work anytime soon, every package I try to add through conda now gives me the familiar "Solving environment: failed" and the forever taking "Examining conflicts". This appears to be going on for 3 years with some quick research and looks like no easy fix.

Comment: You can call cdo from python using my package nctoolkit. Code now in answer. It sounds like you need to create a new conda environment.

Comment: Oh ok! I have nctoolkit installed and working per your help on my last issue. I copied you're code in and get the error: _ValueError: hourmean is not a cdo method!hourmean_

Comment: Thank you for your extensive help but my supervisor has advised me he does not want to run any packages that are not widely know. And seeing as I am having so many issues run cdo and nctoolkit, I ended up finding a solution using xarray. Thanks a ton for your help though!!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with using `xarray` and the function `ds.resample(time="H").mean()`

With `ds` being my named dataset after reading it in as `ds = xr.open_dataset('filename.nc)`